# ROS 2 errors about QStandardPaths

Tags: ros2

I have problems with some commands that throw the following error:

```
ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node
QStandardPaths: error creating runtime directory '/run/user/0/' (Permission denied).
```

How can I solve it? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Welcome at RSE. Please give more information of your setup, ROS 2 distribution, operating system etc.